# Confused about (x,y) order with RectBivariateSpline

Tags: numpy, scipy

I am getting confused about the argument order with `RectBivariateSpline`.  I am reading a set of 2D data which has 343 values along the X axis and 373 values along the Y axis.  The routine that reads the data returns it in the "correct" sense such that when I plot it it matplotlib I get a map that has the correct physical orientation.  It also returns the X values in an array of 343 elements and the Y values in in array of 373 elements which makes sense.

The scipy documentation for `RectBivariateSpline` gives the arguments as:

```
scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x, y, z)
```

However, when I execute

```
spln = scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(xval, yval, zval)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: x dimension of z must have same number of elements as x
```

I can remove the error by executing

```
spln = scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(yval, xval, zval)
```

but now the x and y values are the wrong way round (in a physical sense at least).  Does this mean that the `x` argument to `RectBivariateSpline` refers to the first data dimension of the dataset rather than the physical `x` dimension? I am used to working with data in Fortran-style ordering, which probably is not helping.

In answer to hpaulj's comment, the shapes of the various arrays are:
    xval  (343,)
    yval  (373,)
    zval  (373, 343)

I think the issue is that I am getting confused between 'xy' and 'ij' ordering.  Matpoltlib seems to be using 'xy' ordering so I guess I just need to be careful to transpose the ZVAL array when interpolating using scipy

Comment: Could you post some data? Can be just a reduced dataset which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show us the values of `xval.shape`, `yval.shape` and `zval.shape`

Early in the `RectBivariateSpline` code it does:

```
    x, y = ravel(x), ravel(y)
    ....
    if not x.size == z.shape[0]:
        raise TypeError('x dimension of z must have same number of '
                        'elements as x')
    if not y.size == z.shape[1]:
        raise TypeError('y dimension of z must have same number of '
                        'elements as y')
```

So the number of `rows` of `z` (1st dimension) must match the number of elements in `x`.

When you display a 2d array, rows are the 1st dimension, going down the page, columns the 2nd.  But in a plot, we often expect the first axis, the `x` one to go across the page.

`np.meshgrid` lets you specify:

> ```
> indexing : {'xy', 'ij'}, optional
>     Cartesian ('xy', default) or matrix ('ij') indexing of output.
>     See Notes for more details.
> ```

The difference between 'xy' indexing and 'ij' indexing might be confusing you.  This Spline class is using the 'ij' kind.

An alternative to switching `x` and `y` is to use the transpose of `z`, `z.T`.  Keep in mind that the interpolation points follow the same ordering rules.

---

Simple example

```
In [30]: x=np.arange(10)

In [31]: y=np.arange(15)

In [32]: z=x[:,None]*y[None,:]

In [33]: S=interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x,y,z)

In [34]: S([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
Out[34]: 
array([[  4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  8.,  10.,  12.],
       [ 12.,  15.,  18.]])
```

Contrast the xy v ij in `meshgrid`:

```
In [37]: np.meshgrid(x,y)[0].shape
Out[37]: (15, 10)

In [38]: np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')[0].shape
Out[38]: (10, 15)
```

`z` could have been constructed from the `ij` grids.

```
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')
Z = X*Y
```